# Unable to retrieve data from database to a PDF generated by dompdf package

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

I cannot retrieve data from the database to a PDF generated by the dompdf package. The PDF file gets generated, but it is empty. Any ideas?

**invoiceController**

```
public function pdf_print()
{
    $invoices = Invoice::all();

    $pdf = PDF::loadView('invoice.pdf', compact('invoices'));
    
    return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');
}
```

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  

    @foreach($invoices as $invoice) 

    <input name="taxAmount" id="taxAmount" placeholder="Tax Amount" value="{{ $invoice->taxAmount }}">
  
    @endforeach
   
</body>
</html

Comment: Do you want to show the pdf as a response?

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot we don't know from your question, but my thought is that you may not be loading the PDF correctly.  Is there a **view** file located within your *invoice folder* inside your views folder?  IE DOMPDF is looking to create a view from a pre-made template and your data.  It passes your data to the view and creates the PDF.  So, inside `loadview()` should be a view, not the file name.

E.g.:

```
public function downloadPDF(){
    $data = [
       "full_name"=> "john do",
       "email"=> "john@example.com",
       "age"=>"23",
       "phone"=>"998877XXXX",
    ];
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('nameOfMyPdfVIEW',$data);
    return $pdf->download('nameOfYourFile.pdf');
}
```

Where **nameOfMyPdfVIEW** is the name of a blade file inside your views folder.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I've used once.

```
        $form5_data = FormFive::where('user_id', $user_id)->get();

        foreach ($form5_data as $form) {

            $form5[] = $form;
        }

        $path = Storage::disk('public')->path("forms/form5/$user_email.pdf");

        $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.form5_pdf',['data' => end($form5),'user_email'=>$user_email]);

        return $pdf->save($path)->download("$user_email.pdf");
```